# ClassNotFoundException when instantiating custom logback appender in Play

Tags: playframework, logback

There are tons of similar questions, but I still do not understand the essence of the problem.

- I have SBT project where custom appender is defined.
- Fully qualified class name is specified in logback.xml file.
- Play project explicitly `dependsOn` that project with appender.
- When Play is started the classpath includes the path to the class of appender, but I see the error.

On the other side the same appender is instantiated without any error for Akka project.

So what is so special for loading a class having the absolute path to the directory where class files sit?

Comment: How are you configuring your `logback.xml`? Where are you placing it? Are you passing any system properties to configure logback? The Play dev mode classpath is relatively complex in order to support hot reloading, your applications classes are not on the classpath when Play first starts up, but are added dynamically (and removed, and replaced with new ones every time a reload is done).

Comment: @JamesRoper That became even more confusing. For me classpath is just the path where JVM looks for class file. My naive expectation is that  `dependsOn` makes SBT to set correct classpath and start Play project. From what you say follows that Play has its own way of dynamic resolution only for dev mode. And this behavior is not en extension comparing to prod, but something completely different. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Classloading is rarely that simple, there are often heirarchies of classloaders, in JavaEE for example, and OSGi is a whole other beast. But, you didn't answer my questions, how are you configuring logback? Are you, for example, passing the path to the configuration file with a system property?

Comment: @JamesRoper, nothing special, it's just a logback.xml in `conf` directory. Play just reads it. Commenting out `appender` removes the error.

Comment: And are you using Java or Scala, and if Scala, are you using compile time DI or Guice?

Comment: @JamesRoper Scala, Guice